# Does comma seperated list in a search box indicate ALL or ANY?

Tags: search, user-interface, tags

We have a reporting web site  and in the search screen most of the fields are comboboxes.  We then **AND** all the fields together to get a filtered list of records.  For example if i chose NY in the City dropdown and priority 1 in the priority dropdown and sales in the team dropdown, it would general something that looked like this (pseudo SQL)

```
Show me all record where City = 'NY' AND Priotity = '1' AND Team = 'Sales'
```

We now just added tagging to our records so to support searching by tag(s), we added an additional textbox to search by TAG where you can entered a comma seperated list.

Right now this is an autocomplete textbox which supports multiple entries.([similar to the Multiple Cities (local) example on this page.](http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/demo/)

When we rolled it out people had different expectation on how search would work when you entered multiple items in the text box.  Would it:

1. Do an AND and only return records that had ALL of the tags listed.
2. Do an OR and return records that has ANY of the tags listed.

It turns out that we rolled out #1 but many people expected #2.  Is this just basically preference or is there a default standard here in this example. Our only solution right now is to add a radio button next to the textbox to say **ALL** or **ANY**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your users expect it to work one way then that's the way it should work.

This is a great example of why you should test early and often with actual users.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it is not basically preference, but expectations based on what users experience in other types of searches. The "OR" was probably expected by your users as use of tagging gets pretty close to being like a search engine searching on any word in a text and most search engines do an "OR" and then order the results according to how many terms (tags) were "hit".

If going all the way supporting AND and OR operators is not feasible right now, then I would indeed offer an "All" versus "Any" radio button and default it to "Any".